# Hibernate 3 map Enum

Tags: java, hibernate

We use Hibernate 3 on the project, and as far as i see - there is no org.hibernate.type.EnumType, i've looked through libraries and [this site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhibernate3jar.htm), and it seems there is really no EnumType, or am i missing something?

if it is really so, **How to properly map Enum in hibernate 3?** (using xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, org.hibernate.type.EnumType is part of hibernate-annotations, not simple hibernate, to avoid adding unnecessary library - implemented [UserType](http://blog.xebia.com/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/) and used it to persist enums

Answer (score 0):

If you will use it like a field of some entity, you can declare it like this:

```
import javax.persistence.*;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "yourFields", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "your_entity_id"))
    @Column(name = "yourField")
    private YourEnum yourField;
```

Comment: We use xml mappings, and also i'd like to use enum directly, there is way of doing so, but with EnumType

Comment: You are using *.hbm.xml?